# IIS gives 404 when MS-DOS reserved names are used in parameters values

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, dos

I have an ASP.NET Web API application and I have an action that takes one string parameter, such as:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetById(string id)
{
    // ...
}
```

It is registered accordingly:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Resources", "api/resources/{id}", new
    {
        controller = "Resources",
        action = "GetById"
    });
```

Now, when someone calls **api/resources/con**, IIS gives 404. Almost any other value is OK, like **api/resources/something** or **api/resources/nothing**.

We have looked over and found that none of the [reserved MS-DOS Device Driver Names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74496/en-us) can be used as a parameter value.

This appears to be a global issue, since MSDN has it too:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/con
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/prn
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/nul

Is there any way to allow these names to be used as route parameters values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in Web.config, under system.web.

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```