# WebAPI request throws 404 error ... on same request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have done some looking around and not stumbled onto anything resembling the issue I am experiencing so I thought I would throw it up here and see what, if anything sticks.

I have a controller and method set up.

```
public class BoothAPIController : ITApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetActiveAssetNumbersLike([FromUri] String id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage ret;

        // ... do some processing

        return ret;
    }
}
```

The routes are set up in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CustomApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });


    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "BoothWithDateAPI",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{boothID}/{year}/{month}/{day}");

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

}
```

And these two requests execute flawlessly ...

```
http://localhost:52211/api/BoothAPI/GetActiveAssetNumbersLike/PR
http://localhost:52211/api/BoothAPI/GetActiveAssetNumbersLike/PRN0
```

This one however ... returns a 404 error ...

```
http://localhost:52211/api/BoothAPI/GetActiveAssetNumbersLike/PRN
```

The Header for the failed request looks like ...

```
Cache-Control →private
Content-Length →2879
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Mon, 29 Aug 2016 12:53:08 GMT
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →= [string]
```

While the successful requests look like

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →7731
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Mon, 29 Aug 2016 13:13:43 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles → [string]
```

(Shrugs) I dunno ... I am at a complete loss why the one change in the parameter makes a difference.

Comment: I see a difference on the Content-Type. When it fails, it is sending a text/html. How are you sending these requests? Via a application, or maybe via Postman?

Comment: Also, why are you setting the routes in Global.asax? Don't you have a WebApiConfig file on your App_Start folder?

Comment: The request is identical and being sent from Postman, only the parameter string is different. As far as the Global.asax ... for the moment convenience. I don't have a lot of configuration going on so there was no need to break it out. As the application grows we may refactor it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little digging on this and was surprised myself. Turn out that the parameter you are trying to send `PRN` is a reserved word in [MS-DOS Device Driver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74496)

> Below is a list of default device driver names.
>
> PRN     System list device, usually a parallel port

This question has an answer to the problem:
[IIS gives 404 when MS-DOS reserved names are used in parameters values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710650/iis-gives-404-when-ms-dos-reserved-names-are-used-in-parameters-values/20714926)

But you should be aware of the potentials pitfalls in setting `RelaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to true. See this article by Scott Hanselman:  [Experiments in Wackiness: Allowing percents, angle-brackets, and other naughty things in the ASP.NET/IIS Request URL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)

Comment: Thank you sir! This solved the problem, although I can't imagine why these reserved names have ANYTHING to do with web services ...

Comment: They are related to the File system. The links I provided explain in details why's that. One thing to learn everyday!